# how to load default fragment in frame layout in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have **2 fragment** and  **frameLayout** in mainActivity.
Whenever I run my application I want my **Fragment1** is to be loaded in my frameLayout **default** which is situated in mainActivity.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.prank.fragmentbackstack.MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    >

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Frag.class**

```
import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class Frag extends Fragment {
        String Tag1="frag1";

        Button b;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle saveInstanceState)
        {View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, viewGroup, false);
            b=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: do it in `onCreate` method of your activity...

Comment: how? i really dont know?

Comment: What have you done so far?? show some code

Comment: i want to add Frag.java into Frame Layout default

Answer (score 3):

Use this codes to add dynamically your fragment

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Please, any thoughts on how to display it inside a RN Native Component, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562692/display-android-native-activity-into-react-native-view

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame, new Frag())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this:

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
```

`index = index` of `fragment` you want display

Answer (score 0):

Use this code just replace the frameLayout container with the Fragment1 inside onCreate :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id. frameLayout, new Fragment1())
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in yout Main Activity:

```
frag_name frag_name = new frag_name();
                    FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtframelayout, frag_name, frag_name.getTag()).commit();
```

It inicializes the `fragment` and replaces it in your `FrameLayout`

Hope it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solve using sigleton design pattern.

Inside your `fragment`:

```
public static HomeFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Add `fragment` in your `activity` inside `onCreate` method:

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.yourFrameLayoutId, homeFragment)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make pushfragment class and use whenever you want to add or update.

```
pushFragments(R.id.frame, this, YourFragment, false, false, YourFragment.class.getSimpleName());

public static void pushFragments(int container, AppCompatActivity activity, Fragment fragment, boolean animate, boolean shouldAdd, String tag) {
        FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        if (animate) { //For animation
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit, R.anim.pop_enter, R.anim.pop_exit);
        }

        if (shouldAdd) { //for add in stack
            ft.replace(container, fragment, tag);
            ft.addToBackStack(tag);
            ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else {
            manager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            ft.replace(container, fragment, tag);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```

Pass Frag to pushFragments and add call in your onCreate of Mainactivity.