# Display Android Native Activity into React Native View

Tags: android, react-native

I have a DemoApp Android App which have a `SampleActivity.java` and I want to display it inside and React Native View.

I have created a React Native Component, it loads fine, what I need is to display the content of the `SampleActivity.java` inside of it. I have tried using an Intent but this results in the launching the `SampleActivity.java` full screen, as an separate App rather than inside of the RN `View`.

Current code that launches the `SampleActivity`:

```
    ReactApplicationContext context = getReactApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SampleActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Any thoughts in how to display the Activity inside a RN View?

**Edit:**
I'm still researching but using an Android Fragment may solve this issue, for this I would convert the Activity into a Fragment or create a new Fragment and Add the Activity code. Not 100% sure but it may work.

thank you

Comment: it should be view/fragment but definitely not activity.... you can not display activity in another activity

Answer (score 4):

After some research I saw that the React Native `0.66` version added docss about the use of Native Fragments.

Here you are the docs with an example:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android#1-create-a-fragment

I've followed the steps from the docs and converted the Activity into a Fragment and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't show an activity as a View.

Activities are not views. Each app can have only one activity in started stated at a time. If you want to load a Ui process as a View while it has lifecycles, **Fragment** is for you. Fragments are able to be represented as a view component in the Ui hierarchy.

[**Ref**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities)

Comment: Thank you, yep, I'm taking the Fragment direction. 
Can you provide some example of converting an Activity to a Fragment? What's the approach, create a Fragment and port the Activity over or just convert the Activity to a Fragment? ty